# Why does my for loop give me give me half the expected results

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the pages of all the homes for rent - I have everything working fairly well (I am a beginner - less than a month coding) but my final csv output is half what I am expecting - I check the length of Pages1 and it says I have 84 links, but my final iteration through gives me only 45 links that where processed. Any help thanks.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import re


pages1 =  set()
next_page = set()
csv_output = [ ]


def getLinks(url):
    global pages
    global next_pages
    counter = 4


    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    pageSource = driver.page_source
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(pageSource)

    # first list len check == 0 in shell
    print(len(pages1))

    while counter > 0:

        base_url1 = url
        url_array = str(counter)+'_p/'
        final_url1 = base_url1+url_array
        next_page.add(final_url1)
        counter -= 1
        print(next_page)
        for page in next_page:
            folling_page = page
            print(folling_page+"test")
            html = urlopen(folling_page)
            bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
            for addr_link in bsObj.findAll("a", href=re.compile("^/homedetails/*")):
                if 'href' in addr_link.attrs:
                    if addr_link['href'] not in pages1:
                    newPage = addr_link.attrs['href']
                    print(newPage)
                    pages1.add(newPage)
    # The follow print len shows that I have 84 links in pages1.
    print(len(pages1))

    #The follow for loop only send 43 links through getData(link)
    for link in pages1:
    getData(link)   


def getData(link):

    base_url = 'http://www.zillow.com'
    final_url = base_url+link
    html = urlopen(final_url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)


    try:
    # Address
        address = bsObj.find("header", {"class":"zsg-content-header addr"}).find("h1")
        s_address = address.get_text()


    # beds 
        beds = bsObj.find("span", {"class":"addr_bbs"})
        s_beds = beds.get_text()

    # baths 
        baths = beds.find_next("span", {"class":"addr_bbs"})
        s_baths = baths.get_text()

    # sqft
        sqft = baths.find_next("span", {"class":"addr_bbs"})
        s_sqft = sqft.get_text()

    # rent_amount 
        rent_amount = bsObj.find("div", {"class":"main-row home-summary-row"}).span
        s_rent_amount = rent_amount.get_text()

    # rent_zestiment

        zestiment_holder = bsObj.find("span", {"class":"zsg-tooltip-launch zsg-tooltip-launch_keyword"})
        rent_zestiment = zestiment_holder.find_next("span")
        s_rent_zestiment = rent_zestiment.get_text()


    # Date on Zillow
        for time_posted in bsObj(text=re.compile("Posted")):
            posted = time_posted.parent.get_text()
            if 'hours' in posted:
                date_on_zillow = datetime.date.today()
                posted_date = date_on_zillow
        else:
            days_subtracted = int(re.search(r'\d+', posted).group())
            posted_date = datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=+days_subtracted)

        # subdivision 
        subdivision = bsObj.find(id="hdp-neighborhood").h2
        s_subdivision = subdivision.get_text()

    # property_manager_name 
        property_manager_name = bsObj.find("span", {"class":"snl company-name"})
        s_property_manager_name = property_manager_name.get_text()

    # property_manager_phone
        property_manager_phone = bsObj.find("span", {"class":"snl phone"})
        s_property_manager_phone = property_manager_phone.get_text()

    # disc_of_property 
        disc_of_property =(bsObj.find('div', {'class': "notranslate"}).text)
        s_disc_of_property = disc_of_property.encode("utf-8")
    # url_of_listing 
        main_url = 'http://www.zillow.com'
        url2 = link
        listing_url = main_url+url2
        s_listing_url = listing_url
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None

    csv_data = [s_address, s_beds, s_baths, s_sqft, s_rent_amount, s_rent_zestiment, posted_date, s_subdivision, s_property_manager_name, s_property_manager_phone, s_disc_of_property, s_listing_url]


    csv_output.append(csv_data)


    resultFile = open("output.csv",'w+')
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile)
    wr.writerows(csv_output)
    resultFile.close()

header = ['Address', 'Beds', 'Baths', 'Sqft', 'Rent Amount', 'rent Zestiment', 'Posted Date', 'Subdivision', 'Property Manager Name', 'Property Manager Phone', 'Disc of Property', 'URL']
csv_output.append(header)
getLinks("http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/Clay-County-MO/house,mobile_type/126_rid/6m_days/39.617854,-93.687974,38.946059,-95.129929_rect/9_zm/")
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your post.

Comment: When writing a Web scraper it's good etiquette to put a `sleep(1)` (or at least a `time.sleep(0.1)` between your requests, otherwise you may end up having your IP blocked from larger sites or even crashing smaller ones.

Comment: How do you know you're only calling getData 45 times? Are you sure try clause isn't kicking off and causing silent failures (it just returns). try putting a counter on the actual calls to the function rather than counting output files.

Comment: ok so I put the counter in as you suggested:'code'print(len(pages1))
 for link in pages1:
  counter2 += 1
  print(counter2)
  getData(link) 'code' and I am calling to the getData() function 84 times - but I still am not getting 84 results in my .csv. Any suggestion.

Comment: `resultFile = open("output.csv",'w+')` truncates the file each time you call it so I'd expect the final file only have the results of the 84th call. `'a'` mode may be more appropriate?

Comment: ok changed the except to a print statement and i found out there are several with no phone number entered. I also added 1 second time.sleep's as per the other comment. Thansks Guys.

Comment: Your `except AttributeError as e:` clause causes you to just skip entries with missing data such as phone number. if that's not the intent, you could check your `bsObj.find` calls for `None` instead of juggling the exception.